# Can I expect to sell/make anything from a damaged engine?

Tags: engine

So I am in the process of replacing a damaged engine for my hyundai coupe 4 cylinder.  The damaged engine just had the head gasket changed but the water pump will be removed to my new engine.  I'm not sure exactly whats wrong with the damaged engine but the car is slow, sounds like a tractor and he said 'one of the pistons...compressor...not working or something like that.

Anyway just wondering might this particular engine be of use to anyone\would I be able to get any significant money(£50+) for it or is that not the case in which case I should scrap it?

Comment: any person wanting to part with cash wants to know what they are getting has some use : but you say you don't know what is wrong - I would expect you to pay me to take it away...

Comment: no core charge on the replacement I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cylinder head and block may be salvageable, but it depends on what's happened to the motor, it would need a full damage check over and all tolerances checked.. The block and cyl-head if found to be salvageable would require testing for cracks, skimming, reboring etc etc which for any buyer would be rather costly.

IF someone really needed that engine though it may be worth it for them to take it off you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the metal value from a scrap yard (probably closer to 30 pounds than 50), but it's doubtful you'll be able to sell it as a working engine, given it's problems. It doesn't sound like you've got an especially rare or desirable engine, so the possibility that someone might buy it for the heads or internal parts is pretty low. If you really want to realize some money from it, your best bet is probably cleaning it up and trying to turn it into a coffee table.